# sync issues, certain columns do not get updated

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I keep below tables in sync.

From source to a DW, I do:

```
SELECT @UpdateDate = MAX(UpdateDate)
 FROM [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Payment] 


 SELECT *  INTO #temp    
FROM [LinkedServer].[SF].[dbo].[Payment]
 WHERE UpdateDate >= @UpdateDate 


 DELETE FROM [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Payment]          
 FROM [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Payment] AS A     
 INNER JOIN #temp AS t        
     ON A.Payment_id  = t.Payment_id

INSERT INTO [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Payment]  SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Great! I never had any issues with that.

Then another transfer I do within same sql instance this time:

```
SELECT @LastUpdateDate = MAX(UpdateDate)
FROM [BS].[dbo].[Salesforce_Payment]


insert  @PaymentsVS3
select  (columns…)
from    [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Payment]
where   UpdateDate >= @LastUpdateDate


merge [BS].[dbo].[Salesforce_Payment] as TARGET
    using   (
            select  (columns…)
            from    @PaymentsVS3
            )
            as SOURCE
    on (TARGET.Payment_id = SOURCE.Payment_id)
```

I found issues; the count is always perfect… but some columns do not get updated for example in ReplicatedVS3 I see status = ‘completed’ and in BS I see a different one… So that exactly means that there is something wrong with the code of the merge… But, when I run it manually and I do:

```
insert  @PaymentsVS3
select  (columns…)
from    [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Payment]
where   id = xxxx
```

it gets updated properly, so the merge is working perfect… The only possible reason now is that I am not catching the record in this bit:

```
insert  @PaymentsVS3
select  (columns…)
from    [ReplicatedVS3].[dbo].[Payment]
where   UpdateDate >= @LastUpdateDate
```

How can I troubleshoot this, and know exactly why I see columns don’t get updated.

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` doesn't work on columns, it works on rows.  Of course, you can update only certain columns for rows that trigger an `UPDATE` but the different sections of a merge statement operate on rows of data.  One quick check, does the `SOURCE` and/or `TARGET` have duplicate `Payment_id`'s?

You can debug a `MERGE` statement using the `OUTPUT` clause.  This will allow you to see which rows were inserted, updated, and deleted.  This post gives a good overview of this method: [Merge/Output](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2012/06/12/merge-gives-better-output-options/)